# mysql sqlalchemy mysql isolation error

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, isolation-level

How to set isolation level in sqlalchemy pool configuration. I get the following error when i try to set it as paramaeter in create_engine(...)

```
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 321, in create_engine
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 141, in create
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'isolation_level' sent to create_engine(), using configuration  
MySQLDialect_mysqldb/QueuePool/Engine
```

Comment: Will you please provide some code which create the error. Because `isolation_level` is not available for all database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'isolation_level' parameter is passed as one of the argument to create_engine method

Michael Bayer replied on the SQLAlchemy forum : it's the development version. for the moment you can get it like this: hg.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemy/archive/default.tar.gz

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of sqlalchemy do you have because this functionality for mysql is added in [`0.7.6`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=isolation_level#transaction-isolation-level).

Answer (score 1):

Like explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38438084/1545579), you can achieve the same result by directly issuing the SQL command to set the isolation level. In case of SQL Server, you could do:

```
query = 'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED'
session.connection().connection.execute(query)
```